# How to use single result in While Loop?

Tags: c#, while-loop

Well, my titling is a bit weird I guess. But let me explain my question.

I have a while loop

```
while( GetObj() == null || !GetObj().Initialized ){
    doStuff();
}
```

It would be neat when `GetObj()` isn't called twice per loop.

I've debugged it in another project to be sure that .NET do not avoid calling the method twice. But that isn't the case.

My actual question now is
**Is there a simple way, to avoid calling** `GetObj()` **twice in my loop condition?**

Comment: Why can't you just put it outside the loop and save it in a variable or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This form is less concise, but possibly more readable.

```
var obj = GetObj();
while(obj  == null || !obj.Initialized ){
    doStuff();
    obj = GetObj();
}
```

Comment: Is there *any* (unless the syntax of course) difference to @marcel-n 's answer? I'm wondering since this one gets upvotes and the other one not a single one?

Comment: @Brettetete, One difference is that I answered several minutes earlier, so his answer looks like a duplicate. Normally duplicate answers do not get upvoted. This happens less if the answers are within seconds of each other.

Comment: @Brettetete Also his answer doesn't have the same logic as is in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will help:

```
YourObject obj ;
while((obj = GetObj()) == null || !obj.Initialized) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
var obj = GetObj();

while( obj == null || !obj.Initialized ){
    doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Needs to be inside the while loop, as GetObj might change (most likely does).